# Problem with NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I need to implement a simultaneous search in two search engines. I have two functions:
 ***- (void) searchYoutube: (NSString *)text*** and
 ***- (void) searchYahoo:(NSString *)text***

```
(void) searchYahoo:(NSString *)text{

   NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?appid=%@&output=json&query=%@&results=30", YahooAppId, text];
NSLog(@"URL zaprosa: %@",urlString);

//Create NSURL string from formatted string
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];


NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
if (connection)
{
    NSLog(@"Data will be received from URL: %@", url);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Data couldn't be received from URL: %@", url);
}}
```

Function -searchYoutube: is similar to the above. But when I call query with these two functions, I see

```
2011-06-26 14:06:27.523 TrueSearcher[5373:207] URL query: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=os&start-index=1&max-results=30&alt=jsonc&v=2
2011-06-26 14:06:27.874 TrueSearcher[5373:207] Data will be received from URL: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=os&start-index=1&max-results=30&alt=jsonc&v=2
2011-06-26 14:06:27.875 TrueSearcher[5373:207] URL query: http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?appid=jwGJkT32&output=json&query=os&results=30
2011-06-26 14:06:29.010 TrueSearcher[5373:207] Data will be received from URL: http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?appid=jwGJkT32&output=json&query=os&results=30
```

And that's all. I can't receive any data. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

```
 NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection 
    sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Is wrong. `sendSynchronousRequest` returns an `(NSData *)` with the response data. So, a more correct way to do what you want is

```
  NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection 
    sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

And then you read the response from `responseData`.

You should also take a look at the documentation for [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a suggestion to enhance performance, Answer is already given by uvesten.

sendSynchronousRequest is not a good way to implement, it will not leave control until request is completed, so if it takes time to load, app will not respond to touches.

Instead, you can try

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?appid=%@&output=json&query=%@&results=30", YahooAppId, text];
NSLog(@"URL zaprosa: %@",urlString);

//Create NSURL string from formatted string
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];


NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and implement delegate methods

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    expectedSize = [response expectedContentLength];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    if (objData==nil) { 
        objData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; 
    }
    [objData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
}
```